# Choice with well-ordering constant?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, ho.history-overview

Did someone develop ZFC by means of ZF plus axioms for a binary well-ordering constant, say $\blacktriangleleft$? Are there results that suggested accounts are conservative extensions of ZFC?

Comment: This might be better at hsm forum. Gregory Moore's book on the Axiom of Choice should help with this question.  Gerhard "There Are Better Choices For This" Paseman, 2019.04.29.

Comment: The chances of getting references may not be better at hsm, and in my experience several participants here are interested also in historical issues.

Comment: Well, this is conservative over ZF+V=L, or even V=HOD.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks! I believe this. It would have been interesting to see details.

Comment: Well, under V=HOD there is a parameter-free definable well ordering of the universe. So it's trivial to get the conservative extension.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Many thanks!

Comment: Won't such a theory be equivalent to ZF + global choice? so it would be a conservative extension of ZFC! However if you withdraw set union, then i think the results would differ, i.e. ZF -union+global choice is not a conservative extension of ZF-union+choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This theory is indeed a conservative extension of ZFC.

This can be seen by a class forcing argument. My understanding of the history is that several mathematicians independently noticed this, among them Cohen, Felgner, and Solovay. But only Felgner published the argument.*

Let me sketch the argument. Consider the class forcing $\mathbb P$ whose conditions $p$ are set-sized one-to-one functions whose domain is an ordinal, ordered by extension. This forcing is $\kappa$-closed for every $\kappa$, and thus does not add any new sets. If $G$ is generic for this forcing, then by density we have that $\bigcup G$ is a bijection $\mathrm{Ord} \to V$. From this can be defined a global well-order, call it $\vartriangleleft_G$. Using this as the interpretation for your well-ordering symbol gives you a model of your theory with the same sets as the original model of ZFC. So it must be a conservative extension.

---

* U. Felgner, Comparisons of the axioms of local and universal choice. Fundamenta Mathematicae, vol. 71 (1971), pp. 43–62.